# How to create a string with x numbers of the same character without looping in PHP

Tags: php, string

Is there a nice way (without looping) to create a string constructed by a number of the same characters?

E.g. I know I should add 5 '.' to the beginning of a string. How do I do that without looping?

I don't know beforehand that it should be 5 '.', that can vary. Hence my question.

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use a loop?

Comment: Why do you need this and what is wrong with a loop? What have you already tried?

Comment: @itsmequinn Because I want less code if possile. No real problem using loop otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.str-repeat.php):

```
$output = str_repeat(".", 5); // .....
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function. For example, to concatenate 5 dots together without using a loop, you could do this:

```
$fiveDots = str_repeat('.', 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Answer (score 1):

Use str_pad() function... it's that easy.